# R MODISTools downloading from web service currently not working?

Tags: r, modis

I'm trying to download MODIS FPAR data (and other products) using the R package MODISTools.

It has always worked for me but since about two weeks (beginning of March 2017), I'm always getting the error:

> Downloading from the web service is currently not working. Please try
>   again later.

Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: Are you authenticated? See for that the pymodis documentation: http://www.pymodis.org/info.html#userpw-label

Answer (score 1):

This has been an issue with the MODIS Reprojection Tool, as the files you are trying to download are placed in different folders on their server and the code often fails to parse through each of them. I have a small script that essentially does what the MRT does.

Use the MODIS Data Download Manager through the LP DAAC web portal.

1) This [link](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/data_access/data_pool) will take you to the portal with the download manager. Click on LPDAAC2Disk Download Manager. Here, you have two options - One, to download the manager or use the web interface.

2) I suggest clicking on the web interface. That will take you to this [page](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/data_access/daac2disk).

3) Now draw a polygon around your region. Click on the dataset you need, the time period required and click submit. The download usually takes around 2-3 hours depending on the number of files and the size of the region selected.

4) One can open these files in ArcMap and use the Extract SubDataset tool to get either EVI or NDVI or the data that you need. Alternately, store all these files in a folder and use the python script below to perform the same.

```
 import arcpy,os,re


 arcpy.env.workspace = "F:\\MODIS Data\\"
 out_dir = "F:\\MODIS Data\\EVIData\\"


 rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*")
 count = 1
 for raster in rasters:
   output = str(raster)
   s1 = raster.split('.')[2]
   s1 =s1[1:]
   name = out_dir + raster.split('.')[1] + s1
   print name


 arcpy.ExtractSubDataset_management(raster, name, "1")
```

5) Note, you are basically manually doing what the reprojection tool does. So you are extracting a subdataset and then you need to project it to the projection you need.

Answer (score 1):

Are you bound to use **MODISTools**? Otherwise, this could easily be realized using the [**MODIS**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=MODIS) package as follows:

```
library(MODIS)

## set relevant options
MODISoptions(localArcPath = "/path/to/MODIS_ARC", # raw hdf files
             outDirPath = "/path/to/MODIS_ARC/PROCESSED", # extracted layers
             MODISserverOrder = c("LAADS", "LPDAAC"))

## get latest product collection
cll <- getCollection(product = "MOD15A2H", forceCheck = TRUE)

## download and extract data
tfs <- runGdal(product = "MOD15A2H", collection = cll,
               tileH = 21, tileV = 9, 
               begin = "2017001", end = "2017010", 
               SDSstring = "101100") # extract Fpar, QC and Extra_QC layers
```

Due to recent changes in data policy, downloading data from [LP DAAC](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/) now requires you to create a hidden .netrc file containing [Earthdata](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/) login credentials (which is why I chose [LAADS](https://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/) as standard server for file download). Have a look at [Issue #10](https://github.com/MatMatt/MODIS/issues/10) in the corresponding GitHub repository for further information and `?lpdaacLogin` for help on how to create such a file locally.